# While using chartit with django, I got a stating " <chartit.charts.Chart object at 0x7f19641aba90>" instead of the real chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

While using chartit with django, I got a problem stating " " instead of the real chart.. What may be the possible reasons... Where might I mistaken.. My webserver works well but just chart is not displayed. Thanks in advance....

***In views.py***

```
def moisture_graph(request):
    ds = DataPool(
        series = 
        [{'options': {
        'source':sensor.objects.all()},
        'terms':['time_stamp','soil_moisture']
        }])

    cht = Chart(
        datasource = ds,
        series_options = 
        [{'options':{
        'type':'line',
        'stacking':False},
        'terms':{
        'time_stamp':['soil_moisture']
        }}],
        chart_options =
        {'title':{'text': 'Soil Moisture Graph'},
        'xAxis':{'title':{'text':'Time'}}})

    context = {'sensor_chart':cht}
    return render(request, 'analysis/plot.html', context)
```

***In plot.html***

```
{% extends "orgs/home.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}

<title>AgroTech | Graph Plot</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'orgs/css/content_all.css' %}" />
<link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'orgs/css/sidebar.css' %}" />

<! include highchart and jquery library >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com"></script>


{% block about_css %}

<link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'analysis/css/plot.css' %}" />

{% endblock %}

{% endblock %}    

{% block sidebar %}


    <ul class = 'sidebar_list'>
        <li id = 'list_category'>
            Plot Categories...
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href = "{% url 'analysis:moisture_graph' %}">Soil Moisture Graph</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href = "{% url 'analysis:temp_graph' %}">Temperature Graph</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href = "{% url 'analysis:humidity_graph' %}">Humidity Graph</a>
        </li>
    </ul>


{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}


<div id="content_heading">
{% block plot_heading %}
    Soil Moisture Data Plot
{% endblock %}
</div>


<div id='graph'>
    {% load chartit %}
    {{ sensor_chart }}
    {{ load_charts }}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```